# CBitmap::LoadBitmap() refuses to load a resource

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, mfc

I am working on a DLL which contains a bitmap resource. I imported that bitmap through the Resource View in Visual Studio. The DLL also exports a class which has a function that tries to load the bitmap:

```
BOOL CMyExportedClass::Create(CWnd* pParentWnd /*= NULL*/)
{
    if (!m_bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1))
        return FALSE;
    // ...
}
```

From an MFC application I load the DLL. Inside the applications `InitInstance()` function I then invoke an exported function of the DLL which eventually calls `CMyExportedClass::Create()`.

However, `LoadBitmap()` always returns `0`, which according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc99t364.aspx) indicates either insufficient memory (not the case) or that the resource does not exist.

The bitmap file is part of my DLL project and `IDB_BITMAP1` is defined in the *.rc* file as well as in *resource.h*:

**MyDLL.rc:**

```
IDB_BITMAP1             BITMAP                  "res\\mybitmap.bmp"
```

**resource.h:**

```
#define IDB_BITMAP1                     1034
```

I already checked that the ID has been defined only once. FWIW: At the time `LoadBitmap()` is invoked, the DLLs `InitiInstance()` function has already returned successfully.

What are possible reasons why `LoadBitmap()` refuses to load the resource and how can I fix this?

---

**Edit:**
I can successfully load the resource if instead of `m_bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1)` I do the following:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hCurrentModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0);
if(hBitmap)
    m_bitmap.Attach((HBITMAP)hBitmap);
```

So what's the difference between `CBitmap::LoadBitmap()` and the `LoadImage()` functions here?

Comment: One possibility is that you have a resource with that ID in your host executable. If so, `LoadBitmap` will attempt to load that resource rather than the bitmap in the DLL. Personally I'd be inclined to use `LoadImage`.

Comment: @David Heffernan: There actually were such IDs, but even after assigning a unique ID to my resource the problem persists.

Comment: What happens when you try `LoadImage` passing the module handle for the DLL?

Comment: @David Heffernan: works!! but why? edit ahead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that some other module in the process has a resource with that ID. And the MFC code that searches for the resource is looking in this other module for the module which calls `LoadBitmap`.

My recommendation is to use `LoadImage` and so exert precise control over which module's resources are searched.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what `LoadImage` does differently than `CBitmap::LoadBitmap`? After all I gave the same input and thus `LoadImage` will also have to find the resource by its ID. Why does it succeed where `LoadBitmap` fails? Could it be that `LoadBitmap` uses the wrong module handle internally (i.e. `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`)?

Comment: That is my hypothesis. Ultimately `CBitmap::LoadBitmap` will call `LoadImage`. What matters is the module handle that is passed. By you calling `LoadImage` directly you can extern control over that module handle and not be subject to the whims of MFC.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no search is performed. MFC loads bitmap from the executable file instead of dll according to documentation:

> Loads the bitmap resource named by lpszResourceName or identified by
>   the ID number in nIDResource from  the application's **executable
>   file**.

Edit (to complete answer):

Instead use this (or `LoadImage()` as you have done):

```
m_bitmap.Attach(::LoadBitmap(hCurrentModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1)));
```